# How would i use nested classes in Puppet for this example?

Tags: mysql, class, automation, puppet, mysqltuner

I am trying to install `mysqltuner` for puppet from the forge, already installed properly `mysql` module, but i don´t understand quite well the classes behaviour.
the example is below:

```
class drupal::db {

  class { '::mysql::server':

    # how would i access to ::mysql::server::mysqltuner??? 
    # how  do i should nest to make it work???
    # how can i access the subclass of server "mysqltuner"??? what connector should i use???, I know it like some kind of path to the subclass.
    # Which is the magic connector????
    # Class Tested                        It works
    # ::mysql::server::mysqltuner            No
    # ::mysqltuner                           No
    # mysqltuner                             No
    class { '::mysql::server::mysqltuner':  
      ensure => present
    }
  }

  class { '::mysql::client':
  ...
  }
}
```

I have tried several ways but it didnt work.
i have to use my own cfg file and i need to load mysqltuner so it works with my file.
I really appreciate any answer in the topic.

**Kind Regards.**

Ramiro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking this. `mysql::server::mysqltuner` is not a nested class. It's just a name that represents a significance to `mysql::server`.

Try

```
include ::mysql::server
include ::mysql::server::mysqltuner
```

The `class { '::mysql::server': }` syntax should generally be avoided if not needed.

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer, and how would i pass parameters like removing mysql accounts in this type of implementation???.
Thanks in advance for helping me out

Comment: @Kouen the preferred way to do this is to combine `include` with appropriate [Hiera data](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup). If this is not an option, you can of course replace an `include` statement with a `class { 'name': }` declaration, but please be aware that there are some [caveats](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like).

Comment: Thanks @Felix-frank for the data. Salutations